# Cocos2d:how to implement zooming by pinch

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Cocos2d:
Hello. For a long time trying to do by zooming a pinch, but not impossible. Can you please tell how to implement zooming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to zoom sprites when pinching in cocos2d?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551223/how-to-zoom-sprites-when-pinching-in-cocos2d)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code I'm using in one of my games for pinch zooming.

First of all add this @property to the @interface of the scene (or more likely layer) that you want to pinch zoom:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet * touches;
```

And here is the code you can add to @implementation of the layer

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_touches unionSet:touches];
}

- (void) ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_touches minusSet:touches];
}

- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_touches minusSet:touches];
}

- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch * touch in touches)
    {
        [self pinchZoomWithMovedTouch:touch];
    }
}

- (void) pinchZoomWithMovedTouch: (UITouch *) movedTouch
{
    CGFloat minDistSqr = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    UITouch * nearestTouch = nil;
    UIView * mainView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
    CGPoint newLocation = [movedTouch locationInView:mainView];
    for (UITouch * touch in _touches)
    {
        if (touch != movedTouch)
        {
            CGFloat distSqr = sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints([touch locationInView:mainView],newLocation);
            if (distSqr < minDistSqr)
            {
                minDistSqr = distSqr;
                nearestTouch = touch;
            }
        }
    }
    if (nearestTouch)
    {
        CGFloat prevDistSqr = sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints([nearestTouch locationInView:mainView],
                                                         [movedTouch previousLocationInView:mainView]);
        CGFloat pinchDiff = sqrtf(minDistSqr) - sqrtf(prevDistSqr);
        self.scale += pinchDiff * kPinchZoomCoeff; // kPinchZoomCoeff is constant = 1.0 / 200.0f Adjust it for your needs
    }
}

CGFloat sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(p1, p2);
    return diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y;
}
```

Please note, I've copy-pasted the most part of the code with removing extraneous logic and haven't launch this code. Let me know if you have any trouble with this code.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled multiple touches in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate: you should enable it for window:
    window_.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
as well as for the view:
    glView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
Also, don't forget to initialize the property for my code above:
    self.touches = [NSMutableSet set];

Comment: Best answer on the web for this subject

Answer (score 2):

Because i was looking for it in Javascript for long.
Now try to implement it,

```
var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
        event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ALL_AT_ONCE,
        swallowTouches: true,
        kPinchZoomCoeff: 1 / 200,
        _touches: {},
        thresHold: [],
        onTouchesBegan: function (touches, event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
                var touch = touches[i];
                this._touches[touch.getID()] = touch.getLocationInView();
            }
        },
        onTouchesCancelled: function (touches, event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
                var touch = touches[i];
                delete this._touches[touch.getID()];
            }
        },
        onTouchesEnded: function (touches, event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
                var touch = touches[i];
                delete this._touches[touch.getID()];
            }
        },
        onTouchesMoved: function (touches, event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
                var touch = touches[i];
                this.pinchZoomWithMovedTouch(touch, event);
            }
        },
        pinchZoomWithMovedTouch: function (movedTouch, event) {
            var minDistSqr = 300000;
            var nearestTouch = null;
            var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
            var newLocation = movedTouch.getLocationInView();
            for (var i in this._touches) {
                var location = this._touches[i];
                if (i != movedTouch.getID()) {
                    var distSqr = this.sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints(location, newLocation);
                    this.thresHold.push(distSqr);
                    if (distSqr < minDistSqr) {
                        minDistSqr = distSqr;
                        nearestTouch = location;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (nearestTouch) {
                var prevDistSqr = this.sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints(nearestTouch, movedTouch.getPreviousLocationInView());
                var pinchDiff = Math.sqrt(minDistSqr) - Math.sqrt(prevDistSqr);
                cc.log(pinchDiff);
                target.scale += pinchDiff * this.kPinchZoomCoeff;
            }
        },
        sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints: function (p1, p2) {
            return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
        }
    });
    cc.eventManager.addListener(listener, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be [similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551223/how-to-zoom-sprites-when-pinching-in-cocos2d/20471609#20471609).  I gave a (hopefully complete) answer there.  Please take a look.